# How to animate removal transition of multiple rows from SwiftUI List?

Tags: ios, list, animation, swiftui, transition

Please see this sample view that demonstrates the problem:

```
struct ListRemovalTransition: View {
    let list1 = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
    let list2 = ["A", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K"]

    @State var toggle = false
    var chosenList: [String] {
        toggle ? list1 : list2
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Toggle(isOn: $toggle) {
                Text("Switch List")
            }

            List(chosenList, id: \.self) { item in
                Text(item)
                    .transition(AnyTransition.opacity.animation(.default))
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct ListRemovalTransition_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ListRemovalTransition()
    }
}
```

[image: transition demo]

The desired outcome is that the individual rows fade out when removed without changing position. Instead what's happening seems like all the rows first overlap each other before being removed. I've added a transition with animation to the row Text but this has no impact.

Answer (score 5):

Just add `id(:)` modifier to `List` to remove default animation. Then add `transition(:)` modifier to `List` for your desirable transition. It works perfectly. I just tested on Xcode 11.5. Here is my code...

```
struct ListRemovalTransition: View {
    let list1 = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
    let list2 = ["A", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K"]

    @State var toggle = false
    var chosenList: [String] {
        toggle ? list1 : list2
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Toggle(isOn: $toggle) {
                Text("Switch List")
            }

            List(chosenList, id: \.self) { item in
                Text(item)
            }
            .id(UUID())
            .transition(AnyTransition.opacity.animation(.default))
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

[image: demo]

Thanks. X_X

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This solution definitely works, I'm curious if there's a way to do it without using `.id(UUID())`. While this example wouldn't benefit from it, it's more typical that the List has a single array as the data source so most elements would continue to be in the List after updates. If I understand .id correctly, it would ditch those items and init them again for the updated list which wouldn't be optimal.

Comment: `.id(UUID())` is a unique identifier that makes `List` to rebuild entirely whenever state value is changed. So we cannot see animation. Without `.id(UUID())`, you will see default list transition because `List` does not rebuild and it just changes its data. Currently this is a proper way to remove default transition. I wish `SwiftUI` would provide to be customised as we want.